# Download MP3 files with Python using SearchMP3.mobi service

Tags: python, mp3, urllib2

In my free time I have wrote this script in Python language.

```
import urllib2

class SearchMP3:

    def download(self):

        url = self.url_base + self.title + self.mid_url + self.artist

        mp3file = urllib2.urlopen(self.url_base + self.title + self.mid_url + self.artist + self.end_url)
        output = open(self.title + '.mp3','wb')
        mp3file.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
        mp3file.addheaders = [('Host', 's14.searchmp3.mobi')]
        mp3file.addheaders = [('Referer', url)]
        output.write(mp3file.read())
        output.close()

    def url(self):
        self.url_base = 'http://searchmp3.mobi/'
        self.mid_url = '-mp3'
        self.end_url = '?download=1'
        SearchMP3.download()

    def data(self):
        print 'Welcome to SearchMP3Mobi download service.'
        self.artist = raw_input()
        self.artist.replace('','-')
        self.title = raw_input()
        self.title.replace('','-')
        SearchMP3.url()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SearchMP3 = SearchMP3()
    SearchMP3.data()
```

The script doesn't report any error, but the file size after download is in the KB order. Why? Here I use urlopen, can I use request mode for download mp3 from this site?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried looking at the files? There's a good chance they're HTTP 401 error pages, or just normal HTML pages that have a Javascript redirect to the actual download link, or… well, without actually looking at what you've gotten, no one can do any more than guess.

Comment: Also, what information do you have that leads you to believe that this should work in the first place? And, while we're at it, are you sure that their terms of service allow scraping this way?

Comment: I have tried to print the output a urllib2 request (I some changed the script).
With a request the output is the html file of a page. How do I take the mp3  file?

Comment: I don't know. If you want to reverse-engineer what the website does when you click a "download" link, you'll have to do that yourself, not expect others to do it for you. Most browsers have a way to capture the full HTTP request that the browser makes; do that, and compare what it's doing to what you're doing, and figure out which difference makes the difference.

Comment: Try the webconsole bar in firefox to see all connections being made.

Comment: From a quick check, it looks like the page is downloading something like `http://s14.searchmp3.mobi/d/1WJ2qiOaiK3x4yVDULaqjQ/1377816143/mp3/a/armageddon/Armageddon%20-%20Buzzard.mp3?f=Armageddon%2520-%2520Buzzard.mp3`. Since your request looks nothing like that, it's not surprising that it doesn't download the same thing.

Comment: Take a look abarnert: https://github.com/vivekseth/Spotify-Downloader/blob/master/src/main/listing_sources/LS_SearchMP3_Mobi.java. In this Java source using the same method that I apply in the Python script.